# Check the current real-time audio output level

Tags: bash, audio

I'm trying to detect if the computer is idle or not, then run a script **as root** after x amount of time.

---

I'm using xprintidle to measure the time since last user input has happened. The issue is that xprintidle does not reset if a video or music is being played.

So I've been looking around for a terminal command to be able to see the current audio output level.

Most of the commands I've tested only shows the current volume percentage/value set, and not the real-time audio output level.

I've been able to get all the application sources that outputs audio with this command:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -c 'state: RUNNING'
```

But I end up getting this error message when running it as root:

```
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

---

Does anyone know any command / file to check the current real-time audio output level ?

Or just something as simple to check if **no** audio is being played ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pacmd` uses the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable to find its way to a running PulseAudio daemon. However the connection will be refused if users don't match. This means root cannot directly run `pacmd` to communicate with a regular user's PulseAudio.

Your script running as root can use `sudo` and run `pacmd` as the right user, still with proper `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` (like in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602707/108618)). The script needs to know few values.

As a regular user with access to PulseAudio (i.e. when `pacmd list-sink-inputs` works) invoke:

```
id -u
echo "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
```

The output will be e.g. `1000` and `/run/user/1000` respectively. Then use these values in the script. It will be like:

```
sudo -u '#1000' XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 pacmd … | grep …
```

Note in general variables passed with `sudo VAR=value …` are subject to restrictions (see `man 8 sudo`). I'm not sure if running `sudo` as root changes anything. In case your `sudo` is configured not to allow `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to be set this way, use a shell:

```
sudo -u '#1000' sh -c 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 pacmd …' | grep …
```